# Floating gate mos with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

We've covered in a digital electronics class the floating gate mos used to construct EPROMs.
I have searched in the circuitikz documentation but I've found no way of drawing it.

I am pretty new to tikz in general, I don't really know how to create it.
In class we have used the following symbol, but I don't really care if an equivalent symbol is used.

[image: FGmos]

Could you please help me drawing it?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a HEMT with no base and add the missing parts:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/length=3cm}
    \node[hemt, nobase] (t) at (0,0) {};
    \path
        let
            \p1 = ($ (t.gate) - (t.nobulk) $),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
            \p2 = ($(t.inner up)-(t.inner down)$),
            \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
        in
            ($ (t.gate)!0.8!(t.nobulk) $) node[draw, rectangle, anchor=center, minimum width=.1*\n1, minimum height=\n2, inner sep=0pt] {};
    \coordinate (tmp) at ($(t.gate)!0.6!(t.nobulk)$);
    \draw[thick] (tmp |- t.inner up) -- (tmp |- t.inner down);
    \draw (tmp) -- (t.gate);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: floating gate 1]

The "new" mos is scalable (as shown by `\ctikzset{bipoles/length=3cm}`).

If you need to use this symbol more often you can define a own command for it. I would suggest the use of subcircuits, but keep in mind subcircuits are still experimental (v. 1.3.5):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ctikzsubcircuitdef{flmos}{gate, G, drain, D, source, S, fgate, bulk, nobulk, inner up, inner down}{%
    coordinate (#1-center)
    node[hemt, nobase] (#1-t) at (#1-center) {}
    coordinate (#1-fgate) at ($ (#1-t.gate)!0.8!(#1-t.nobulk) $)
    let
        \p1 = ($ (#1-t.gate) - (#1-t.nobulk) $),
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
        \p2 = ($(#1-t.inner up)-(#1-t.inner down)$),
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
    in
        (#1-fgate) node[draw, rectangle, anchor=center, minimum width=.1*\n1, minimum height=\n2, inner sep=0pt] {}
    coordinate (#1-tmp) at ($(#1-t.gate)!0.6!(#1-t.nobulk)$)
    (#1-tmp |- #1-t.inner up) edge[thick] (#1-tmp |- #1-t.inner down)
    (#1-tmp) -- (#1-t.gate)
    coordinate (#1-gate) at (#1-t.gate)
    coordinate (#1-G) at (#1-t.G)
    coordinate (#1-drain) at (#1-t.drain)
    coordinate (#1-D) at (#1-t.D)
    coordinate (#1-source) at (#1-t.source)
    coordinate (#1-S) at (#1-t.S)
    coordinate (#1-bulk) at (#1-t.bulk)
    coordinate (#1-nobulk) at (#1-t.nobulk)
    coordinate (#1-inner up) at (#1-t.inner up)
    coordinate (#1-inner down) at (#1-t.inner down)
    (#1-center)
}
\ctikzsubcircuitactivate{flmos}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) \flmos{flmosA}{};
    \draw (flmosA-S) node[circle,inner sep=1pt,fill]{} \flmos{flmosB}{D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: floatin gate 2]

Comment: This is a great answer! I think you are the first user of subcircuits that I know ;-).

Comment: As resizing the FG mos is fundamental in my circuit, this is the best solution for me (sorry for forgetting to specify this behaviour in my question!).

To use this, I had to download the latest `.sty` file for circuitikz, which seems to work fine with other circuits I have drawn in the past.

Thanks mais!

Answer (score 3):

The easy solution is to take a mosfet and draw an extra line in the center gap.  You can also increase the line thickness and the gap size, or even create a whole new transistor type, depending how much work you want to put into it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \node[nmos] (A) {};
  \draw ($(A.centergap) + (0,0.27)$) -- ($(A.centergap) + (0,-0.27)$);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This gives me an error about centergap. This anchor does not seem to exist no version 1.3.2. I've downloaded the latest version (1.4.3 at the time of writing) from [here](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/). This is now working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, border =2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

    \psset{unit = 1.5cm, linejoin=1}
    \begin{pspicture}(-0.4,-2.3)(3.5,2.3)
    \psgrid[gridcolor=Gainsboro, subgriddiv=1, gridlabels=0pt](-1,-3)(4,3)
    \psset{linewidth=1.5pt, arrows = c-c}%
    \psline(0,0)(1,0)
    \psline(1,1)(1,-1) \psline(1.4,1)(1.4,-1)
    \psline(3,2)(3,1)(2,1)(2,-1)(3,-1)(3,-2)
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]